# Почему не меняется src картинки при клике?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelector(".myImg").src = "hackanm.gif";
}
```

```html
<img class="myImg" src="img/main_center.png">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Точнее, в html документе src меняется, но картинка та же

Comment: "Точнее, в html документе src меняется, но картинка та же" --- да не может быть))  и да....префикс `img/`  где?)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5nw7et49/